# PG::Error : result has been cleared rails serilization

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

in my database we have a serialized value in one column as like below

consider table is **test** and filed is **meta**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ID          Name                meta
------------------------------------------------------------------------
726345      test               - :status: :success
                                 :result: !ruby/object:PG::Result {}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

while writing query using Active record  `Test.select('meta').where(:id=> 726345)`

it is throwing error is  : `PG::Error Exception: result has been cleared`

for remaning columns Name and ID is working fine. i figured out error with result key, but i don't know how to solve this issue.

any help ??

Rails - 5.1, ruby - 2.2.5, mysql - 5.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like Result object within the database is a empty object.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, that meta field is from database, it has status and result keys

Comment: You might clearify better when you add some ruby-on-rails code.

Comment: @RaymondNijland what else data you need ?  i haven't write any ruby code. i have Test model. i am just doing Test.select('meta').where(:id=> 726345). it is throwing error

Comment: And how did you save that data within your example data? Sure it must be ruby-on-rail code right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland. yes, result = c.exec(sql), c is connection to postgres. i am running some sql query. and storing result returned by c.exec(sql) in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

On write, you serialized empty `PG::Result` object. When querying, rails is trying to deserializes it with `PG::Result.new`, which fails

```
> PG::Result.new

PG::Error: result has been cleared
```

To fix this, you can just clear the column. It has no practical use, anyway.

*I don't really understand why you serialize from result postgtresql to mysql, though*

Comment: Thanks for you explanation,  i have lot of records in my database with same PG::Result object, some of columns have object with keys, some of columns are empty like above. can u please suggest me proper way to query even though if PG::Result object is empty

Comment: @shakeel sorry, didn't have time. I'll reply with a workaround in couple hours

Comment: Thank u, waiting for reply

Comment: @shakeel sorry to keep you waiting. Hope the question is still relevant. I've looked at it again. It seems that *any* `PG::Result` converted to yaml would be empty. Do I understand you correctly that in your meta are lots of other data, besides `PG::Result` and you can't simply remove column?

Comment: Yes, for example if i run `connection.exec("select * from table");` then `PG::Result` is not going to be empty.